# How can I drag a file onto MacVim and make it open in a new buffer instead of new tab?

Tags: macvim, tabbed-user-interface

I have MacVim 8.2.2576. When I drag a file onto it from the Finder it opens in a new tab. I have seen the `:help drag-n-drop` but I did not see any option as I prefer.

Is there any ways to configure like that?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacVim has a preferences dialog in the usual (for a Mac) place.  Its General setting "Open files from applications" controls what happens when you drop a file onto the app.  The preferences let you choose between "in a new window" and "in the current window".  The latter has a pop-up to control exactly what you get when you open files in the current window: splits, tabs, windows, and/or updating the arglist.